# How can i create an instant app for my existing reactnative app using Google instant play?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-instant-previews

I am having one basic application which is built using the react native,now i want to create an instant application for this main app(may be a single page "Helloworld.js"just for experimenting to create instant app).

I have gone through web for the solution but couldn't find any official document or answers which can fullfil my question.

So i request here,If someone know how to create a one page helloworld instant app for my existing react native app.

one more thing i want to use Google instant play for this and want to test and run on local emulator only.

thank you.